# Maclauren series of $ (1+x)^{1/x} $

Tags: calculus

Was curious about this after seeing that $$ \lim_{ x \rightarrow 0}{ \left[ \cfrac{1}{x} \cdot \left((1+x)^{1/x} - e\right) \right]} = -e/2 $$  An answer to my question would solve the analogous questions about the higher-order rates of convergence of $ (1+x)^{1/x} $ to $ e $.  But it is hard to find order in the derivatives of $ (1+x)^{1/x} $.  Wondering if this sequence has been studied.  Here's a little computation:
[image: Mathematica computation of first 9 Taylor coefficients]

Edit: it is interesting to observe these values when they are converted to decimal form.  They are approaching $(-1)^n$.  Viz.,
[image]
A proof of this fact would be interesting if a closed-form formula cannot be found.

Comment: By the way, in Mathematica `D[expr,{x,n}]` is the $n$th derivative of `expr` with respect to $x$. There's no need to define your own function as you seem to have done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per https://oeis.org/A055505 and https://oeis.org/A055535, the coefficient can be expressed as a finite sum in terms of [Stirling numbers of the first kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_number) ${n\brack k}$, so it would be
$$
f(x)=\sum_{n\geq 0}\left(e\sum_{k=0}^{n}{n+k\brack k}\frac1{(n+k)!}\sum_{l=0}^{n-k}\frac{(-1)^l}{l!}\right)x^n,
$$
or when expressing the inner sum in terms of [Incomplete gamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incomplete_gamma_function) 
$$
f(x)=\sum_{n\geq 0}\left(\sum_{k=0}^{n}{n+k\brack k}\frac{\Gamma(n-k+1,-1)}{(n+k)!(n-k)!}\right)x^n.
$$

Now I don't know the derivation behind this, but by Maple verification it seems to be correct (someone else can surely give more details on math behind this).

Comment: Accepted this answer.  I still haven't done the exercise of showing that these coefficients approach $ \pm 1 $ as $ n \rightarrow \infty $, but this is satisfying enough for me.